# Run any line/command in x64dbg

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

Is it possible, to run whichever line I want? 
For example, if it is at black position, and i want to run the RED CIRCLED command:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to do that, neither in right click or etc... Just want to select that line and do i.e. "RUN THIS LINE"

Comment: You can change the instruction pointer to that line with right click -> set new origin at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Set New Origin Here* option in the context menu of the disassembly view to change EIP/RIP to the selected line:

[image: context menu]

In x64dbg commands this option can be expressed as: `cip = dis.sel()`.

Comment: and then I press the "Continue" button to execute that line, right?